# Jquery fullcalendar dayclick event creation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, fullcalendar

So I am attempting to use fullcalendar's dayclick to trigger a popup that can be used to save the event to a database. The event will then be able to be viewed in the fullcalendar's calendar view. My current javascript for the popup is:

```
dayClick: function (start, end, allDay) {
    $(".popup").show(); // show's pop up
    $(".title").focus(); // auto focus on the field
    var start = Date.parse(start) / 1000; // parse the start time to retain value
    var end = Date.parse(end) / 1000; // same but with end
    $(".submitForm").click(function () { // on submission
        var title = $(".title").val(); // gets title value
        if (title != "") { // if the title exists run script
            $.post("insertscript.php", { title: title, start: start, end: end, allDay: allDay }, // be sure to filter data 
            function () {
                $(".title").val(""); // clear title field
                start = ""; // clear start time
                end = ""; // clear end time
                calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
                calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
            });
        }
        $(".popup").hide(); // hide pop up box
    });
},
```

I know ajax is probably the best route for saving the event but have yet to figure out how to work it properly. Any help is appreciated thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you using draggable events? If so, the `drop` method is where you'd want to use a small AJAX routine to save the `evObj`'s properties to a database.

Comment: What actually happens at the moment?